# Gridview is not binding outside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have button click event when i click button it is firing the event and calling the method but the grid view is not binding.Please help me to rectify the issue.

```
<asp:updatepanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>


<asp:Button ID="btnrefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnrefresh_Click" />

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnrefresh" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>
 </asp:updatepanel>  
//GridView outside updatepanel
```

Comment: If the Gridview is outside the updatepanel and your button click only triggers an update on the updatepanel, why would you expect the gridview to refresh?

Comment: Place the grid view inside the same update panel, or another with update me set to 'always'